# Angular router seems to work but doesn't load component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a path structure like this: `/events/100/drawing/200` and events and drawings are separate modules with their own routing tables, like:

```
// Event ID routes
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: ':eventID', 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Drawings & Results' },
    component: EventComponent,

    children: [
        {
            path: 'drawing', 
            loadChildren: () => import('@app/modules/event-drawing/event-drawing.module').then(mod => mod.EventDrawingModule)
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: ':drawingID', 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Drawing' },
    component: EventDrawingComponent
},
];
```

There is a breadcrump that shows me the current path and the routing seems to work. But in any case the `EventComponent` is loaded, but not the `EventDrawingComponent` as expected.

I also tried this to remove the `EventComponent` from:

```
// Event ID routes
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: ':eventID', 
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Drawings & Results' },

    children: [
        {
            path: 'drawing', 
            loadChildren: () => import('@app/modules/event-drawing/event-drawing.module').then(mod => mod.EventDrawingModule)
        }
    ]
}
```

Now the `EventDrawingComponent` is loaded but of course `/events/100` wont work anymore. Please can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` somewhere in your parent template. The Angular router renders the loaded component there. Without it, your component class will be instantiated, but it cannot be rendered.

Also, make sure you have added the `RouterModule` to the `imports` array in your parent module.